# which signal did supervisor send to express.js to restart the server

Tags: node.js, signals, node-supervisor

All:

**[UPDATE]: Some posts mentioned that: In windows, there is no signal mechanism, so "SIGINT" can not work in Windows Node.js**

I got one question when I deal with express termination:

I want to detect the shutdown signal of express server, so I set these:

```
process.on('exit', function(code) {
  console.log("exit disconnect.");
});

process.on('SIGINT', function(code){
  console.log("interrupt disconnect.");
});

process.on('SIGQUIT', function(code){
  console.log("quit disconnect.");
});
```

in `bin/www`. And start the server with `supervisor bin/www`

but when I use supervisor to monitor and restart the server, none of them get called, could anyone tell me **which signal** I should bind to process to monitor the shutdown of server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supervisor doesn't support sending signals to end a process.

Look here:
https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/53